# Armazenar dados do arquivo CSV numa lista

Tags: java, csv, arraylist

Eu estou lendo um arquivo CSV com 9 milhões de linhas, e preciso transformar cada linha em um objeto e armazenar numa lista ou buffer para posteriormente gravar em um arquivo de acesso aleatório.

Quando eu tento adicionar os objetos do investidor na lista dá o seguinte erro quando chega em 6.462.547 milhões de linhas:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu posso contornar esse erro?

[Link para o arquivo que eu estou lendo](https://dados.gov.br/dataset/investidores-do-tesouro-direto)

A minha função leitura (OBS.: A classe TextFile pode ser substituida pelo BufferedReader):

```
public List<Object> lerDadosCSV(String arquivoCSV, JProgressBar progressBar, JTextField textField, int tipo) {
    long indice = 0;
    numeroTotalLinhas = numeroTotalLinhas(arquivoCSV) * 2;
    try (TextFile textFile = new TextFile(arquivoCSV)) {
        DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#,###");
        String linha;
        List<Object> records = new ArrayList<>();
        while ((linha = textFile.readLine()) != null) {
            if (indice != 0) {
                records.add(tipo == 0 ? montaEstoque(linha.split(";")) : montaInvestidor(linha.split(";")));
            }
            textField.setText(decimalFormat.format(indice));
            progressBar.setValue((int) (indice * 100 / numeroTotalLinhas));
            progressBar.setString((int) (indice * 100 / numeroTotalLinhas) + "%");
            indice++;
        }
        return records;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Função montaInvestidor:

```java
    public static Investidor montaInvestidor(String[] splitLinha) {
        try {
            boolean operou = (splitLinha[10].contains("s|S")) ? true : false,
                    situacao = (splitLinha[9].contains("a|A")) ? true : false;
            Investidor investidor = new Investidor(Integer.parseInt(splitLinha[0]), formataData.parse(splitLinha[1]),
                    splitLinha[2].trim(), splitLinha[3].trim(), splitLinha[4].trim(), splitLinha[6].trim(),
                    splitLinha[7].trim(), splitLinha[8].trim(), Integer.parseInt(splitLinha[5]), situacao, operou);
            return investidor;
        } catch (NumberFormatException | ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite Matheus! O seu programa esta dando um estouro na pilha(stackoverflow hahaha), esta usando mais memoria do que a aplicação tem disponível, caso esteja usando o tomcat acho que não é o seu caso, pode aumentar de forma manual, e pode tbm otimizar o código, fazer menos coisas dentro da função, por exemplo so criar os objetos e depois formata-los

Comment: Eu não uso nenhum framework nesse projeto